# CAML with 'And' gives no results?

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml-query, caml

I am pulling results from a SharePoint Online list without problem with this...

`<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='department'></FieldRef><Value Type='Text'>HR</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>`

but this gives me no results (even though there are)

`<View><Query><Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='department'></FieldRef><Value Type='Text'>HR</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='licenses'></FieldRef><Value Type='Text'>yes</Value></Eq></And></Where></Query></View>`

Is my syntax wrong?

Thanks
P

Comment: Is licences actually a boolean field?

Comment: What is the data type of licenses column?

Comment: Single line of text

Comment: Use case sensitive values - check if you are using correct values. Also, verify name of columns just in case

Comment: Thanks. Value will always either be blank or yes. I am using the same case. The column name is correct. Totally at a lose with this one!

Comment: Try adding indexing on both department and licenses column: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-an-index-to-a-list-or-library-column-f3f00554-b7dc-44d1-a2ed-d477eac463b0

Comment: I think that the 'yes' is being stored with a newline at the end. How would I account for that in CAML? thanks

Comment: Ganesh you were helping me with a flow which adds the 'yes' to a row. I can't see how it's adding yes with a carraige return?

Comment: if(greater(length(outputs('Get_user_profile_(V2)')?['body/assignedLicenses']),0),'yes','')